# How to avoid retain cycle with delaying block invocation on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, objective-c-blocks, uiviewanimation

I am really stumped with this one. I have been reading all the info I can get my hands on about how to properly handle variables inside blocks.

Note: I am not using arc.

So, say I have an animation that looks like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
    textCard.alpha = 1.f;
    self.dotView.alpha = 1.f;
    self.subtitles.alpha = 0;
}completion:^(BOOL finished){
    [self.playerLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
    self.playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.vidPlayer];
    self.playerLayer.frame = self.vidView.bounds;
    [self.vidView.layer insertSublayer:self.playerLayer atIndex:0];
    [self.subtitles removeFromSuperview];
    self.subtitles = [sub autorelease];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 delay:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
        textCard.alpha = 0.f;
        sub.alpha = 1.f;
    }completion:^(BOOL finished){
        self.queuedVid = NO;
        if (self.shouldPlay == YES) {

            [self.vidPlayer play];
            [self setCurrentVideoSettings];
        }
        else{
            self.shouldPlay = YES;
        }

        [textCard removeFromSuperview];
        textCard = nil;
    }];
    }];
```

Now this code probably looks a little arbitrary but here is a very real world example of something I have to do.

Here are my two problems:

1. If I leave this as is and the class (tries) to get deallocated during the invocation of this block, it will not release.
2. If I change self to     `__block typeof (self)  weakRef = self;` then if the class gets deallocated before the second block can run, it crashes because it is trying to reference my deallocated self.

I know I just must not understand how this works, but if anyone can shed some light, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Your two problems are incompatible. Either the animation block extends the lifetime of `self`, or `self` dies in the middle and the animation block starts referencing a garbage object. The first "problem" is generally considered a feature.

Comment: @KevinBallard Extending the lifetime would be fine. But keeping it entirely from being able to deallocate is not. I'm not sure what you mean by "garbage object" as I am not using arc. It just crashes. I need some way of either canceling the block invocation or...I need my variables to somehow return nil when it tries to invoke, as to avoid the crash.

Comment: It doesn't keep the object from ever deallocating. Once the completion block has fired, it drops the reference to `self`, which releases it. If you're seeing the object *never* get deallocated, then you've got something else going on.

Comment: "garbage object" means that the object "self" is a pointer to a memory location. When the object is deallocated, then that memory location might be overwritten with arbitrary data ie. garbage.

Comment: @KevinBallard I didn't understand how the blocks work. Now it makes perfect sense to me. So the issue was that in the delayed invocation I tell my movie player to play. I worked around this and now my class deallocates as soon as the block finishes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't worry about retain cycles created by references to `self` in inline animation blocks. The block will retain self when the animation begins, and release it when the animation block finishes executing.

Imagine someone does something that invokes your animation. Then, before the animation completes, they pop that view controller off the navigation stack. The navigation controller releases your controller, but the animation block continues to retain it. When the animation completes (off screen), the block will release what should be the last reference to your controller, and it will be deallocated.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I figured this out with the help of Kevin Ballard's comments.