# When is reference to self in block a retain cycle?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks

I've got a problem that is probably fairly common.  In an ARC environment, a block that needs to reference self will outlive self.  I'm aware of the convention to use `__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;` in blocks to avoid retain cycles.  The problem is that we do need to retain self.  So my question is: When does a reference to self in a block create a retain cycle?  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487549/how-to-avoid-retain-cycle-with-delaying-block-invocation-on-ios) post suggests that in animation blocks, reference to self is ok.

I had also considered a solution like the following, but am not sure it changes anything:

```
__block typeof(self) blockSelf = self;

[someObj someMethodTakingCallback:^{
    //do some stuff
    blockSelf = nil;
 }];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get a reference cycle if `self` retains the block in addition to the block retaining `self.

Comment: I guess then the question becomes "When does self retain the block?"  I assume in the example above - passing a block to another object for execution - it's not.  Correct?

Comment: Without seeing more scope, the code you posted should not result in `self` retaining the block.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you would have a retain cycle if self holds a reference to someObj since someObj is probably holding a reference to self.  It's actually a retain cycle if there's any retaining reference path from self to someObj.

Comment: Why do you say that `someObj` is probably holding a reference to `self` if `self` holds a reference to `someObj`. That makes no sense.

Comment: someObj is holding a reference to the block (that's the probable reference, we can't be sure based only on what we see here)  The block definitely holds a reference to self.  Hence someObj is probably holding an (indirect) reference to self.

Comment: The "cycle" part comes into play if in addition to that indirect reference from someObj to self, there's a retained path from self to someObj (for instance, if someObj is actually a property or instance variable of self

Comment: someObj is holding a reference to the block in my case.  But self is not holding reference to the block and is not holding reference to someObj

Comment: In that case, Jon, you probably don't have a retain cycle.

Comment: @David Why do you say `sombeObj` is holding a reference to the block? It's not. Why do you say the block is holding a reference to `self`? It's not (at least as far as we can tell).

Comment: I was extrapolating and assuming that the block was invoked at a later time, I thought I saw that statement made in a comment somewhere, but don't see it now.  If block is used only within the context of someMethodTakingCallback then it's possible (probable) that it's not holding a reference to the block.